# Notification not received firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am not receiving any notification. I am using firebase function. The function is working properly. I am getting success message in the firebase log.

My index.js function:

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');

let admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/messages/{pushId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
  if (!event.data.current.val()) {
  return console.log('User ');
}
         const message = event.data.current.val();
        const senderUid = message.from;
        const receiverUid = message.to;
        const promises = [];

        if (senderUid == receiverUid) {
            //if sender is receiver, don't send notification
            promises.push(event.data.current.ref.remove());
            return Promise.all(promises);
        }

        const getInstanceIdPromise = admin.database().ref(`/users/${receiverUid}/instanceId`).once('value');
        const getSenderUidPromise = admin.auth().getUser(senderUid);

        return Promise.all([getInstanceIdPromise, getSenderUidPromise]).then(results => {
            const instanceId = results[0].val();
            const sender = results[1];
            console.log('notifying ' + receiverUid + ' about ' + message.body + ' from ' + senderUid);

            const notification = {
                data: {
                    title: sender.displayName,
                    body: message.body,
                    //icon: sender.photoURL
                }
            };

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(instanceId, payload)
                .then(function (response) {
               console.log("Successfully sent message:", payload);
                    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                });
        });
    });
```

I am getting token and the database is also proper. 
MyFirebaseMessaging class

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
       @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

            // Check if message contains a data payload.
            if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

                String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
                String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("text");
                String username = remoteMessage.getData().get("username");
                String uid = remoteMessage.getData().get("uid");
                String fcmToken = remoteMessage.getData().get("fcm_token");

                // Don't show notification if chat activity is open.
                if (!ChatMainApp.isChatActivityOpen()) {
                    sendNotification(title,
                            message,
                            username,
                            uid,
                            fcmToken);
                } else {
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new PushNotificationEvent(title,
                            message,
                            username,
                            uid,
                            fcmToken));
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
         */

        private void sendNotification(String title,
                                      String message,
                                      String receiver,
                                      String receiverUid,
                                      String firebaseToken) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, chat.class);
            intent.putExtra("receiver", receiver);
            intent.putExtra("receiverid", receiverUid);
            intent.putExtra("firebasetoken", firebaseToken);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
        }

    }
```

My manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.main.food">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"

        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".firebaselogin"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".FirebaseIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 </manifest>
```

I have specified the service in the manifest inside of the application tag and I am getting the token and I have stored the same in the users table.

OnMessageReceived is never called, I tried debugging it.

Please can someone help me with this.

Comment: have you specify you service class in `AndroidMenifest.xml`?

Comment: Check this https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

look at this [Set Up a Firebase Cloud Messaging Client App on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Maybe you missed the setup of a FirebaseInstanceIdService.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

```
    public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

/**
 * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
 * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
 * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
 */
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
}}
```

You need this service for registration purpose so the fcm can find your device.